# PHP MD5/base64 encryption to C# md5/base64 encryption

Tags: c#, php, encryption, md5, base64

I am in the process of try to integrate some C# ASP.NET webservice into my PHP application however there is a big problem.  The way the C# webservice does the encryption is not compatible with the way PHP does the MD5 encryption.  I have found solution for converting the C# MD5 to PHP MD5 however I can't change the C# code.  Is there a way to change the way that PHP does its MD5 encryption to match C#?  The c# encryption works like this:

```
MD5CryptoServiceProvider MD5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
byte[] bs = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToEncrypt);
String myString = Convert.ToBase64String(MD5.ComputeHash(bs));
```

Comment: Try sharing your PHP code also. And technically, MD5 is not encryption, but a one-way hash algorithm.

Comment: Neither MD5 nor Base64 are [encryptions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption); MD5 is a [cryptographic hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) and Base64 is a [base conversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) to represent binary data with 64 printable ASCII characters.

Comment: my code is base64_encode(md5(utf8_encode('123456789')))

Comment: apparently I needed to do base64_encode(md5('123456789', true))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since MD5 is a published algorithm, the implementations in PHP and c# are identical. The only difference is the string format of the byte sequence they produce. PHP produces a hex string, so you just need to convert from hex to Base64.

Comment: base64_encode(md5('123456789', true)) will also work as noted by ryanzec - I saw no mention as to why exactly this works so I will briefly explain - the optional boolean value, which defaults to false, declares that you want a hexadecimal representation of the md5 hash as opposed to the raw binary representation

Comment: Thank you for this solution.

It has worked for me

Answer (score 0):

This could be an encoding issue. Make sure your PHP version gets the UTF-8 representation of the string, apply MD5, then convert to a base 64 string, and you should be fine.

Comment: well I am doing base64_encode(md5(utf8_encode('123456789')))) but not getting the same as C#

Answer (score 0):

This is an encoding issue I have had before between PHP and C#.

If PHP is manipulating ISO-8859-1 strings (which is probably your case), you can do:

```
md5(utf8_encode($stringToEncrypt))
```

The best way to test is to try a very simple string with a-z content, which should work fine regardless of any encoding issue. It that works and the whole thing doesn't, you have an encoding issue.

You could also do:

```
byte[] bs = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(stringToEncrypt);
```

and

```
md5($stringToEncrypt)
```

will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I see what is your problem:

```
String myString = Convert.ToBase64String(MD5.ComputeHash(bs));
```

will make a Base64 string out of a pure MD5 array hash.

PHP will first make an hex representation of the MD5 hash then base64-encode it.

You should get the hex result first as described here:

http://blog.stevex.net/c-code-snippet-creating-an-md5-hash-string/

and then base64 encode the string.

Comment: yea, I know that but like I said, I can't change the C#, only the PHP